Can anybody explain what 耍流氓 is?
The following is a post of July 24, 2024 on Weibo.com by a well-known influencer 洛之秋 who is a college teacher based in Nanjing, Jiangsu.
儿子看了各地城市标语，突然问：赌和毒我知道是什么，黄到底指的是？
我愣了一下：黄就是男生在外面调戏女孩子，耍流氓。
儿子：怎么算耍流氓？
我权衡了一下，说：譬如女生走在路上，男生对着她吹口哨。
儿子：这不是主动和女生表演音乐吗？为什么是耍流氓？
我：…如果女生想听，就是音乐；如果女生不想听，就是耍流氓，懂吗？
儿子：哦…
What does 耍流氓 really mean?

耍流氓 = act hooligan

In simpl word: Sexual disturbance

流氓 means ruffian or rogue. 耍流氓 means acting like a ruffian.

A 流氓 is a person who engages in unwelcome, anti-social behaviour. As a verb, 耍流氓 means to act like a 流氓, to do something anti-social.
In the question, 洛之秋 is trying to describe to a child what the 黄 refers to in 黄赌毒. 洛之秋 gives an example of a man who wolf-whistles at women. In this case, 耍流氓 here includes harrassment-type behaviour which would be annoying and uncomfortable but fall short of actual physical assault (It's not a very accurate explanation of 黄, but clearly 洛之秋 doesn't want to go into details).
You can see another example of 流氓 behaviour in this song, where a road accident occurs but the driver who was responsible runs off.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VImVx8cJCIc
流氓 is also a category of low-level crime which is usually translated as "hooliganism", in Western jurisdictions this would probably be called a misdemeanour.

耍流氓 here has connotations of sexual harassment, which is against the law in many countries.
A hooligan or a ruffian may also 耍流氓, but that does not necessarily follow.

如果女生想听，就是音乐

Dad is embarrassed to tell the boy exactly what 黄 means.
Why does 黄色 indicate pornography and vulgarity? Blame the English!
历史变迁
1894年，英国创刊了一家杂志，名字就叫《黄杂志》，一批有世纪末文艺倾向的小说家、诗人、散文家、画家等，围绕该杂志形成一个被称为“颓废派”的文艺集团。他们的作品，有时带有一点色情意味，但不能算淫秽。
然而第二年4月3日，当时极负盛名的英国剧作家王尔德（O.Wilde），因同性恋的罪名遭到逮捕。而逮捕他时的一个小插曲，使得《杂志》名声大受损害。当时报纸上说，王尔德在被捕时胁下还夹了一本《黄杂志》，于是人们想当然地认为这杂志和王尔德同样是“见不得人”的，第二天就有人到《黄杂志》的出版商门前示威，用石头将橱窗玻璃砸得粉碎。
其实王尔德被捕那天，胁下夹的书是法国作家比尔·路易的小说《爱神》，碰巧这本小说和当时法国的许多廉价小说一样，也是黄封面的。这种小说称为“yellowback”，也被认为是不登大雅之堂的。
《黄杂志》也好，“yellowback”也好，都使得“黄色”与性、色情、恶俗等等概念发生了联系。但就在同时，大洋彼岸的美国报业，则另有一番“黄色”景象。
当时纽约的《世界报》和《日报》，为了发行量而展开疯狂竞争。先是约瑟夫·普利策买下了《世界报》，用绘声绘色、耸人听闻的报道和对政治腐败的攻击，赢得了全美报纸的最大发行量。1895年矿业巨头之子W.R.赫斯特买下了《世界报》的对手《日报》，他所采用的手段更是变本加厉，甚至把专为《星期日世界报》画极受读者欢迎的连环漫画《黄色小子》的画家也挖了过来。当时两报广泛采用通栏大字标题、彩色连环画、大量图片等等手法，竭力迎合读者。这段时期被称为“黄色新闻”时期，类似于现代的“标题党”。这就是西方世界的“黄色”──色情也好，媚俗也好，都被认为是低级的东西。
